# Marshalling C dll code into C#

Tags: c#, c, char, unmanaged, marshalling

I have the following C-code signature in a dll:

```
extern __declspec(dllexport) unsigned char *
funct_name (int *w, int *h, char **enc, int len, unsigned char *text, int *lp, int *mp, int *ep)
```

The C function can modify w, h, enc, lp, mp, and ep (though the latter three can be null and it won't do anything.

I'm using the following in C#

```
[DllImport("iec16022ecc200.dll", EntryPoint = "iec16022ecc200", ExactSpelling = false, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
            static extern IntPtr CallEncode(
            [In,Out,MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] Int32[] width,
            [In,Out,MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] Int32[] height,
            [In,Out,MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] ref StringBuilder encoding,
            int barcodeLen,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] StringBuilder barcode,
            IntPtr lenp,
            IntPtr maxp,
            IntPtr eccp
            );


public void Foo (string textToEncode,out int width, out int height) {
            StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder(textToEncode);
            StringBuilder encoding = new StringBuilder(new string('a', text.Length));

            Int32[] w = new Int32[1];
            Int32[] h = new Int32[1];


            string encodedStr = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(CallEncode(w, h, ref encoding, text.Length, text, (IntPtr)0, (IntPtr)0, (IntPtr)0));
            width = w[0];
            height = h[0];
}
```

I am getting a SystemAccessViolation and I'm not entirely sure when my problem is.

Answer (score 3):

Don't pass a StringBuilder reference to a unmanaged method that takes a char*. StringBuilder content is unicode (wchar).

Instead, replace the StringBuilder parameter with and IntPtr parameter and allocate a appropriate size buffer using Marshal.AllocHGlobal.

Also I don't think passing a StringBuilder to unmanaged code using "ref" is supported by the .Net marshaller.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned that the 'char **enc' parameter may be modified by the callee, this could be causing the 'SystemAccessViolation' error. A StringBuilder can be dereferenced and modified by the callee, provided it does not exceed the StringBuilders capacity.

Answer (score 1):

[`StringBuilder` should not be passed by reference using `out` or `ref`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164193.aspx#S4).

```
    //...
    [In,Out,MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] ref StringBuilder encoding,
    //...
```

Remove the `ref` keyword from the `encoding` parameter that is of type `StringBuilder`.  That is what is probably causing your `SystemAccessViolation`.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to pass a string from C++ to C# in Unity. And all I got was gibberish. Finally after I saw your comment @popcatalin I discovered the solution using AllocHGlobal from C# to allocate memory for the string.

This is my C++ function:

```
extern "C" void UNITY_INTERFACE_EXPORT UNITY_INTERFACE_API TestString(char* str, int len)
{
    strcpy_s(str, len, "C++ String!!! UniversalCpp");
    return;
}
```

This is at the top of the C# script in Unity:

```
#if WRCCPP
    [DllImport("UniversalWRCCpp", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
#else
    [DllImport("UniversalCpp", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
#endif
    private static extern void TestString(IntPtr str, int len);

private IntPtr myPtr = IntPtr.Zero; // Pointer to allocated memory
```

And this is my C# script in Unity calling that function:

```
int sizeInBytes = 100;
myPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(new IntPtr(sizeInBytes));
TestString(myPtr, sizeInBytes);
Debug.Log("ANSI " + Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(myPtr)); // This prints the correct format
```