# How to pass and receive data from a char * from C# to an unmanaged C++ DLL

Tags: c#, .net, marshalling, dllimport, unmanaged

- I do not have complete access to the DLL source, only the header.
- The names of the parameters in my actual code are more descriptive

I am trying to make a call to an unmanaged DLL that takes in all char * variables, with two of them acting as "return" values. in1-8 are the inputs, in9 and 10 are char * of length 512, and are passed in empty. Once the call completes, they should be filled with the result data.

Here's a sample definition that I'm attempting to work with:

```
[DllImport("mydll.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr foo(
    IntPtr in1,
    IntPtr in2,
    IntPtr in3,
    IntPtr in4,
    IntPtr in5,
    IntPtr in6,
    IntPtr in7,
    IntPtr in8,
    ref IntPtr result1,
    ref IntPtr result2);
```

Here's my call:

```
IntPtr param1 = Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni("testdata");
IntPtr param2 = Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni("testdata");
IntPtr param3 = Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni("testdata");
IntPtr param4 = Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni("testdata");
IntPtr param5 = Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni("testdata");
IntPtr param6 = Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni("testdata");
IntPtr param7 = Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni("testdata");
IntPtr param8 = Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni("testdata");
IntPtr param9 = IntPtr.Zero;
IntPtr param10 = IntPtr.Zero;

foo(param1, param2, param3, param4, param5, param6, param7, param8, ref param9, ref param10);
```

To print an IntPtr, I'm doing:

```
string str = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(param9);
Console.WriteLine(str);
```

In a "sample" given to me, the C++ call looks like this:

```
char result1[512]="";
char result2[512]="";
foo("testdata", "testdata", "testdata", "testdata", "testdata", "testdata", "testdata", "testdata", result1, result2);
printf("%s,%s\n",result1,result2);
```

The problem: In every way I've tried, including char[512] converted to byte[], StringBuilder size 512, IntPtr, etc. The param9 and param10 values are empty on every return. Can anyone help me figure this out? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
After some helpful comments below and more google searches I patched my messy code to work. Here's the edits:

```
[DllImport("mydll.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr foo(
    IntPtr in1,
    IntPtr in2,
    IntPtr in3,
    IntPtr in4,
    IntPtr in5,
    IntPtr in6,
    IntPtr in7,
    IntPtr in8,
    IntPtr result1,
    IntPtr result2);
```

I got rid of the ref on the two result char arrays.

```
IntPtr param1 = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi("testdata");
IntPtr param2 = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi("testdata");
IntPtr param3 = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi("testdata");
IntPtr param4 = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi("testdata");
IntPtr param5 = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi("testdata");
IntPtr param6 = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi("testdata");
IntPtr param7 = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi("testdata");
IntPtr param8 = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi("testdata");
IntPtr param9 = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(512 * sizeof(int));
IntPtr param10 = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(512 * sizeof(int));

foo(param1, param2, param3, param4, param5, param6, param7, param8, param9, param10);
```

Above I allocated param9 and 10 instead of IntPtr.Zero

```
//printing..
string str = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(param9);
```

**Also a much simpler way using Strings, thanks to the answers below:**

```
[DllImport("mydll.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr foo(
    string in1,
    string in2,
    string in3,
    string in4,
    string in5,
    string in6,
    string in7,
    string in8,
    StringBuilder result1,
    StringBuilder result2);
```

then:

```
StringBuilder resultA = new StringBuilder(512);
StringBuilder resultB = new StringBuilder(512);

foo("test", "test", "test", "test", "test", "test", "test", "test", resultA, resultB);
```

printing:

```
Console.WriteLine(resultA.ToString());
```

It looks much better now and actually works now, thanks guys! It's so easy to get confused with 50 tabs of google searches open.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/803488/marshalling-c-dll-code-into-c-sharp

Comment: Did you try the StringBuilder without a ref parameter? I think that should work.

Comment: @slfan, I have tried without the ref on stringbuilder and it comes back empty, still. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Are you sure that your C++ method is correct and copies some data into the char array?

Comment: @slfan Yes, I should have added another line to the original post. It prints the result1 and result2 char arrays immediately after the call in the C++ code and they are filled with data. I will add that change now.

Comment: StringToHGlobalUni() is wrong, it should be StringToHGlobalAnsi().  It is just simpler to declare these arguments as *string* instead.  Except the last two, StringBuilder.  This is an atrocious function, avoid needing it.

Comment: @HansPassant Swapping them all to Uni fixed my problem, thank you. I will also mess around with strings/stringbuilders more. This is the first time I've used unmanaged code in C# so my code is a giant mess of the 50 tabs worth of solutions I've seen so far. I'm also going to edit the OP to show the working version for future readers...

Comment: Oh, I see you found the answer while I was typing mine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assume you have the following c declaration

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) {
    void foo(char * input, char * output);
}
```

I would define the following C# definition:

```
[DllImport("mydll.dll", EntryPoint="foo")]
public static extern void Foo(string input, StringBuilder output);
```

and the call would be like this:

```
string input = "input";
var output = new StringBuilder(512);
Foo(input, output);
```

If possible try to avoid unsafe code.